# What is happening in the this.setState({array})?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx, prop

the line this.setState({array}) is it replacing the array obj in this.state...?

```
class myComp extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            array: [],
            mouseIsPressed: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {     
        const array = getInitialArray();
        this.setState({array});
      }

      render() {
          return(
          );
      }
}
```

When I console log rite after that line this.state is the same as before that line.

Also, the line is usually used like this.setState({abc: abc}); how is that line diffrent?

Comment: https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/

Comment: What is that `getInitialArray` function

Comment: It's an initializer that creates an array of objects.

Comment: Move your console.log to render function, you will see that data is already there.

Comment: The reference to the shorthand is what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

> the line this.setState({array}) is it replacing the array obj in this.state...?

Yes.

`{ array }` is a shorthand for `{ array: array }`. When you call setState and pass it an object, react will update every property listed in that object, and leave all other properties unmodified. So in this case `array` will be updated, but `mouseIsPressed` will not.

> When I console log rite after that line this.state is the same as before that line.

setState is asynchronous (sometimes, at least). A log statement after setState is not guaranteed to see the new value. The purpose of setState is to cause the component to rerender, and on the new render it will have the new value. You can stick your console.log in render to verify that it is rerendering, and has new data.

It's rarely needed, but setState does allow you to pass a function to it as the second parameter. This function will be run once the setState is complete:

```
this.setState({ array }, () => {
  console.log('all done!', this.state)
})
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `setState({ array })` is shorthand for `setState({ array: array }` in javascript - seems like the asker was confused about this syntax. They are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks all...the short had is what I was missing.